# Pandas function read_html not encoding macros characters

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting data from wiki as such:

```
url = 'https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vir#Latin'
tables = pd.read_html(url, encoding='latin1')
print(tables[1])
```

Result:
macron-ed letters are garbled, such ar viry in stead of virī

What am I doing wrong?

python3 panda 1.1.4

Comment: View source shows `<meta charset="UTF-8">` so perhaps try with encoding='UTF-8'?

Comment: negative, but thanks

Comment: The page shows a different table with javascript turned off and what it does show without javascript matches pandas' output with encoding='UTF-8'.

Comment: At least for index 1.

Comment: Browse the page with javascript off then print all tables and you'll see that the accented characters are all displayed properly with encoding='UTF-8'. See repl.it [demo](https://repl.it/@JustinEzequiel/pandasAsefrQWerASDf).

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that javascript is rendering the macron of virī? BTW your demo also shows accents in place of macrons in some words. perhaps somethis is up with my machine then, thanks! I dont have to stick with pandas, I'll look for some other ways.

Comment: No. You are comparing what you see when you open the page in your browser which executes javascript with what you see when you read the page using pandas which does not execute javascript. You need to understand the difference.